# Why is my layout getting re-rendered in Nextjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I have a simple root layout in Nextjs (app router) that renders a navbar and the children below it.

ROOT LAYOUT

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Russo_One } from "next/font/google";
import Navbar from "./_components/Navbar";

export const russo = Russo_One({ weight: "400", subsets: ["latin"] });

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Sportly",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In the documentation, it states that...

> A layout is UI that is shared between multiple pages. On navigation,
> layouts preserve state, remain interactive, and **do not re-render**.
> Layouts can also be nested

So, I am confused as to why this is happening. I only noticed it because I imported a Google font and used it in the navbar. However, when I change the page, the font weight resets for a brief second before reappearing. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

NAVBAR COMPONENT

```
import { Link, Typography, Box } from "@mui/material";
import { russo } from "../layout";

export default function Navbar() {
  console.log("navbar rendering...");
  return (
    <nav className="/*STYLES*/">
        <h1 style={{fontWeight: "400" /* STYLES*/}} className={russo.className}>
          SPORTLY
        </h1>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any chance this is just a dev run problem ? Do you get the same problem if you preview it from a build run ?

Comment: @LSE Unfortunately, not. The problem also occurs in the build run.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without stackblitz copy or something, but I would

1. Check if it's really a re-render problem.
   https://jsramblings.com/how-to-check-if-your-component-rerendered-and-why/
2. If it's not re-rendering, and it's just a problem of css being injected by js, consider loading the font as recommend in here:
   https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10-2#automatic-webfont-optimization